# Mismatch between Php and Extension module

Tags: php, sql, php-extension

I am trying to install the following php extension. Microsoft Drivers for SQL Server  for PHP.
I have tried both versions of the [driver](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098) but both seem to mismatch the version of php i am running. I looked around and it appears I have to recompile the modules in order to match the php api version. But I don't have any idea how to do this.

Any ideas on how to make this work? Or maybe a simpler way to use PHP 5.4.7 to access SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with some tricks, its not recommended but it will work fine and in my case, it has not crashed yet :)

Check your `phpinfo()` page for:

**1-PHP extension API Number**

**2-Thread safe or non-thread safe version**

**3-(Windows) compiler version**

1-For building your extension you need **php.lib**. It is in your PHP-server `dev` directory.

2-You need PHP header files for compiling your extension, after including PHP header files, go to `PHP/Zend` directory and open `zend_modules.h` file and change the `#define ZEND_MODULE_API_NO 20060613`to your PHP extension API number for example change it to `#define ZEND_MODULE_API_NO 20090626`.

3- If you use windows based servers the compiler version is important(VC8 - VC10), if your PHP was compiled with VC8, build the extension in VS2008 or use VC8 for building your project.

If you encounter any wired error just comment it. I spent 3 months to make this worked ;)

Comment: In fact if you compile your extension with your PHP server header files and library, you don't need any extra changes which are mentioned above. But before building your extension, check for these parameters to ensure the release version of your extension.